# Getting around floating point error with logarithms?

Tags: logarithm, floating-point-exceptions

I'm trying to write a basic digit counter (an integer is inputted and the number of digits of that integer is outputted) for positive integers.  This is my general formula:

```
dig(x) := Math.floor(Math.log(x,10))
```

I tried implementing the equivalent of `dig(x)` in Ruby, and found that when I was computing `dig(1000)` I was getting 2 instead of 3 because `Math.log` was returning 2.9999999999999996 which would then be truncated down to 2.  What is the proper way to handle this problem?  (I'm assuming this problem can occur regardless of the language used to implement this approach, but if that's not the case then please explain that in your answer).

Answer (score 1):

To get an exact count of the number of digits in an integer, you can do the usual thing: (in C/C++, assuming `n` is non-negative)

```
int digits = 0;
while (n > 0) {
  n = n / 10; // integer division, just drops the ones digit and shifts right
  digits = digits + 1;
}
```

I'm not certain but I suspect running a built-in logarithm function won't be faster than this, and this will give you an exact answer.

I thought about it for a minute and couldn't come up with a way to make the logarithm-based approach work with any guarantees, and almost convinced myself that it is probably a doomed pursuit in the first place because of floating point rounding errors, etc.

Comment: Avoiding floating point entirely for this calculation is almost certainly the right approach, if Kvass isn't specifically interested in understanding floating-point roundoff.

Answer (score 0):

From *The Art of Computer Programming* volume 2, we will eliminate one bit of error before the floor function is applied by adding that one bit back in.

Let `x` be the result of `log` and then do `x += x / 0x10000000` for a single precision floating point number (C's `float`). Then pass the value into `floor`.

This is guaranteed to be the fastest (assuming you have the answer in numerical form) because it uses only a few floating point instructions.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this solution.  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: The idea is to add a minimal amount of error to the floating point value, and then round down -- roughly equivalent to finding the nearest integer by adding 0.5 and then rounding down, but the introduced error has to be calculated to it's scaled appropriately to the floating point number you're using.

This doesn't actually solve the roundoff problem, but it makes it round off in a way that may be closer to what humans expect.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point is *always* subject to roundoff error; that's one of the hazards you need to be aware of, and actively manage, when working with it. The proper way to handle it, if you must use floats is to figure out what the expected amount of accumulated error is and allow for that in comparisons and printouts -- round off appropriately, compare for whether the difference is within that range rather than comparing for equality, etcetera.

There is no exact binary-floating-point representation of simple things like 1/10th, for example.

(As others have noted, you could rewrite the problem to avoid using the floating-point-based solution entirely, but since you asked specifically about working log() I wanted to address that question; apologies if I'm off target. Some of the other answers provide specific suggestions for how you  might round off the result. That would "solve" this particular case, but as your floating operations get more complicated you'll have to continue to allow for roundoff accumulating at each step and either deal with the error at each step or deal with the cumulative error -- the latter being the more complicated but more accurate solution.)

If this is a serious problem for an application, folks sometimes use scaled fixed point instead (running financial computations in terms of pennies rather than dollars, for example). Or they use one of the "big number" packages which computes in decimal rather than in binary; those have their own round-off problems, but they round off more the way humans expect them to.

Comment: -1 for not offering an actual solution and merely saying that the OP is doomed to fail.

Comment: Accepted, though I think this is an important limitation to understand. You can round the value off to look more like what you expected, but that will not make it any more accurate; less so, if anything.

Comment: +1 for saying the right thing, that floating point is the wrong solution to this problem